# What is causing my script to fail on my computer, but run fine in another?

Tags: python-2.7, version, networkx, pyomo

I am running a script for network flow optimization and collaborating with another individual. I am building a model using networkx and feeding it to pyomo. My script does not run and the model is not being built. The only error reported is

> ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object build_pipe[_s1_3,s]

where `build_pipe[_s1_3,s]` is an edge with parameters defined in a `csv` file that certainly defines all the needed inputs. While this error keeps my script from running, the other individual is able to run the script just fine. Using networkX 2.1 and pyomo 5.6.1 on python 2.7.

We compared package versions and those are the same. The only difference I can think of is that he is running his script on Spyder and I am running mine on jupyter notebook. This error came up in the past but some editing (marked by `#**`) resolved it. Would not know what to change this time around.

```
def create_graph(nodefile, arcfile):
    g = networkx.DiGraph()
    # read the data files
    # We assume the first column of the node file is the node name
    # We also assume the arc file's first two columns are (node start, node end)
    nodes = pandas.read_csv(nodefile)
    arcs = pandas.read_csv(arcfile)
    # create the nodes and associated data
    nameCol = nodes.columns[0]
    for num,arow in nodes.iterrows():
        g.add_node( arow[nameCol], **(dict(arow))) 
    # create the arcs and associated data
    firstNodeCol = arcs.columns[0]
    secondNodeCol = arcs.columns[1]
    for num,arow in arcs.iterrows():
        g.add_edge( arow[firstNodeCol], arow[secondNodeCol], **(dict(arow))) 
    return g

def create_pyomo_network_lp_primal(g,cost_field='Cost',capacity_field='Capacity',node_imbalance_field='SupplyDemand', interdiction_field='xbar'):
    # Create the model
    model = pe.ConcreteModel()
    # Tell pyomo to read in dual-variable information from the solver
    model.dual = pe.Suffix(direction=pe.Suffix.IMPORT)

    # Associate the graph with this model
    model.g = g

    # Create the problem data
    model.node_set = pe.Set( initialize=g.nodes() )
    model.edge_set = pe.Set( initialize=g.edges(), dimen=None) #**added ", dimen=None"

    model.edge_cost = pe.Param( model.edge_set, 
            initialize=lambda model, i,j: model.g.adj[i][j].get(cost_field,0))
    model.edge_capacity = pe.Param( model.edge_set, 
            initialize=lambda model, i,j: model.g.adj[i][j].get(capacity_field,0))
    model.node_imbalance = pe.Param( model.node_set, 
            initialize=lambda model, i: model.g.node[i].get(node_imbalance_field,0))
    model.edge_delay_on = pe.Param( model.edge_set, 
            initialize=lambda model, i,j: model.g.adj[i][j].get(interdiction_field,0), mutable=True)

    # Compute nCmax
    nCmax = model.g.number_of_nodes() * max([data.get(cost_field, 0) for e0,e1,data in model.g.edges(data=True) ])
    model.nCmax = nCmax
    model.delay = pe.Param(initialize= 2*nCmax + 1, mutable=True)

    # Create the variables
    model.y = pe.Var(model.edge_set, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals) #flow across each edge
    model.build_pipe = pe.Var(model.edge_set, domain=pe.Binary) #binary whether we build a pipe for each edge #**added model.build_pipe which is a binary decision variable on whether or not the model chooses to build a pipe along a specific edge. Initialize it at 1 so that the model will solve (i.e. all pipes start with a 1, meaning that all pipes are initially built, then the model removes pipes to improve the objective)

    model.UnsatSupply = pe.Var(model.node_set, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals)
    model.UnsatDemand = pe.Var(model.node_set, domain=pe.NonNegativeReals)

    # Create the objective
    def obj_rule(model):
        return  pe.summation(model.edge_cost, model.build_pipe) + model.delay * pe.summation(model.edge_delay_on, model.y) + model.nCmax * pe.summation(model.UnsatDemand) #**removed " + model.nCmax * pe.summation(model.UnsatSupply)" which adds a penalty to the objective if not all of the supply is used. Updated the first OBJ term to use "model.build_pipe" instead of "model.y", which means that the objective depends on what piping network we build, not on the amount of flow we send over the pipes

    model.OBJ = pe.Objective(rule=obj_rule, sense=pe.minimize)


    # Create the constraints, one for each node
    def flow_bal_rule(model, n):
        expr = 0
        if model.g.in_edges(n):
            expr += pe.summation(model.y, index=model.g.in_edges(n))
        if model.g.out_edges(n):
            expr += - pe.summation(model.y, index=model.g.out_edges(n))
        supply_node = (model.node_imbalance[n] < 0)
        demand_node = (model.node_imbalance[n] > 0)
        constr = (expr == model.node_imbalance[n] + model.UnsatSupply[n]*int(supply_node) - model.UnsatDemand[n]*int(demand_node) )
        if isinstance(constr, bool):
            if constr == True:
                return pe.Constraint.Feasible
            return pe.Constraint.Infeasible
        return constr

    model.FlowBalance = pe.Constraint(model.node_set, rule=flow_bal_rule)


    # Create the capacity constraints, one for each edge
    def capacity_rule(model, i, j):
        return model.y[(i,j)] <= model.edge_capacity[(i,j)] * model.build_pipe[(i,j)] #** added " * model.build_pipe[(i,j)]" which means that the capacity of an edge is zero unless we choose to build it (if we choose to build pipe(i,j), then model.build_pipe[(i,j)] will equal 1, otherwise it equals 0)

    model.Capacity = pe.Constraint(model.edge_set, rule=capacity_rule)


    # Solve the model
    #model.create()#** WARNING: DEPRECATION WARNING: the Model.create() method is deprecated.  Call Model.create_instance() to create a concrete instance from an abstract model.  You do not need to call Model.create() for a concrete model.
    model= resolve_mip(model)

    # Print the model objective
    print 'Primal objective function value:', model.OBJ()
    return model

# ============================================================================
# This is a useful function, in case you want to re-solve a model in the
# interpreter.  Remember that if you dynamically want to change model
# parameters, you have to declare them as 'mutable' in the model.  If you look
# above, we've declared edge_delay_on and delay as mutable in this case.
# ============================================================================

def resolve_mip(model, tee=False):
    model.preprocess()
    solver = pyomo.opt.SolverFactory('cplex')
    results = solver.solve(model, tee=tee, keepfiles=False) #** removed " , options="mip_tolerances_integrality=1e-9 mip_tolerances_mipgap=0") "

    # Check that we actually computed an optimal solution, load results
    if (results.solver.status != pyomo.opt.SolverStatus.ok):
        logging.warning('Check solver not ok?')
    if (results.solver.termination_condition != pyomo.opt.TerminationCondition.optimal):  
        logging.warning('Check solver optimality?')

    #model.load(results) #** WARNING: DEPRECATION WARNING: the Model.load() method is deprecated for loading solutions stored in SolverResults objects.  By default, results from solvers are immediately loaded into the original model instance.

    model.g.OBJ_val = model.OBJ()

    # Load solution data back into the networkx object 
    if hasattr(model, 'y'):
        for e in model.edge_set:
            model.g.adj[e[0]][e[1]]['flow_val'] = model.y[e].value
            model.g.adj[e[0]][e[1]]['build_pipe'] = model.build_pipe[e].value #**added build_pipe to the model output solution

    #if hasattr(model, 'dual'): #** remove the following 3 lines. I'm not sure what this code snippet does, but it was throwing errors. I think it has to do with running the interdiction version of the model.
     #   for n in model.FlowBalance.iterkeys(): 
      #      model.g.node[n]['dual_val'] = model.dual[ model.FlowBalance[n] ]

    if hasattr(model, 'x'):
        for e in model.edge_set:
            model.g.adj[e[0]][e[1]]['attackActive'] = model.x[e].value

    if hasattr(model, 'UnsatDemand'):
        for n in model.node_set:
            model.g.node[n]['UnsatDemand'] = model.UnsatDemand[n].value
            model.g.node[n]['UnsatSupply'] = model.UnsatSupply[n].value

    return model

# ============================================================================
# Here, we are printing a nice report on the solution to the screen.  You have
# to pass a networkx object, with the flow_val field loaded.
# ============================================================================

def print_solution(g):

    edges = sorted(g.edges(data=True))
    for e0,e1,data in edges:
        if data.has_key('attackActive') and data['attackActive'] == 1:
            print 'Interdict arc %s -> %s'%(str(e0), str(e1))
    print

    nodes = sorted(g.nodes(data=True))
    for n,data in nodes:
        if data.has_key('UnsatSupply') and data['UnsatSupply'] > 0:
            print 'Remaining supply on node %s: %.2f'%(str(n), data['UnsatSupply'])
    for n,data in nodes:
        if data.has_key('UnsatDemand') and data['UnsatDemand'] > 0:
            print 'Remaining demand on node %s: %.2f'%(str(n), data['UnsatDemand'])
    print

    for e0,e1,data in edges:
        if data.has_key('flow_val') and data['flow_val'] > 0:
            print 'Flow on arc %s -> %s: %.2f'%(str(e0), str(e1), data['flow_val'])
    print

    #** added the following printout
    print "Pipes Built:"
    for e0,e1,data in edges:
        if data.has_key('build_pipe') and data['build_pipe'] > 0 and len(e0) > 3:
            print '   %s: %s-inch'%(str(e0), str(e0)[-1])
    print

    print '----------'
    print 'Total cost = ', g.OBJ_val 


# ===============================================================
# Now that we've defined all our functions, lets do something....
#
# First, lets read the data. 
# ===============================================================

g = create_graph('nodes_multi_pipe.csv', 'edges_multi_pipe.csv')

# ===============================================================
# Lets solve and print the flow when there are no
# interdictions.
# ===============================================================

mPrimal = create_pyomo_network_lp_primal(g, capacity_field='Capacity')

print 'Flow without interdictions:'
print_solution(mPrimal.g)
```

Comment: Could you supply a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Try to delete all unnecessary code and supply an example of input.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed stack trace? It's not clear where in your implementation that error is being thrown.